# Lambda Node JS Shopify API Call

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I have been trying to resolve this for the past couple of days and no luck, i am fairly new to Node Js and Lambda. I am trying to create an API with lambda and when i call this new API, i want to create a new redirect object in Shopify. I have the following code running in my function

```
const http = require('https')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return httprequest().then((data) => {
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
    return response;
    });
};
function httprequest() {
     var username = "shopify-api-private-username";
     var password = "shopify-api-private-password";
     var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
    
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'store-name.myshopify.com',
            path: '/admin/api/2020-04/redirects.json',
            port: 443,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': auth,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"redirect":{"path":"http://www.apple.com/forum","target":"http://forums.apple.com"}})
        };
        
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
            }
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                } catch(e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });
        // send the request
       req.end();
    });
}
```

As much i keep changing the code I keep getting the following error. After adding a console log on the response i see the following, not sure if this  is a Lambda/Node Response or Shopify:

[image]

```
Function logs:
  servername: 'store-name.myshopify.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'store-name.myshopify.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 4,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /admin/api/2020-04/redirects.json HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Basic base64code_replace_for_security_reasons=\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'Host: store-name.myshopify.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 0\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/admin/api/2020-04/redirects.json',
    _ended: false,
    res: [Circular],
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '4': null,
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      incoming: [Circular],
      outgoing: [Circular],
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: false,
      onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncomingClient]
    },
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      authorization: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

By the way i am doing this directly on a new Lambda function. The only file i have is index.js.

Node Version
Node.js 12.x

Comment: 400 response means that you are sending [Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) to this api , check your request data.

Comment: i am new to Node and i was wondering the difference between the section res.on.data and res.on.end is? I see both section work with the body. I have implemented this on Postman and works correctly. When i do console.log on both section, nothing gets printed on the terminal section, Thank you

Comment: @Carlos on data captures the data chunks one by one. On end lets you know that no more data will come, hence the whole request was read and can be handled. Maybe even use a client library such as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), this will help you making proper requests.

Comment: Does this code work when you run it locally? If not can you run the request in Postman?

Comment: I started with Postman to make sure the request and fields were ok, and once it was, i started a Lambda function. I then got a NodeJS example from some other Stackoverflow answer and used that as a template. An have been trying to debug for the past couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short explanation of why your code is not working is because of Bad Request as rightly pointed out in comments. It is a bad request because you are not actually sending the payload with your request. The code that you have got from Stack Overflow, may have been for GET request and simply adding **body** property to **options** object will not work. Because as per [Node.js docs for HTTPS](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_new_agent_options), **options** object does not has any property named **body**.

As per [Node.js docs for HTTP request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback), you need to send POST data using **write** function.

```
// Write data to request body
req.write(postData);
```

To fix your code, add Content length property and write post data. Check code comments.

```
    const http = require('https')
    
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        return httprequest().then((data) => {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            };
        return response;
        });
    };
    function httprequest() {
         var username = "shopify-api-private-username";
         var password = "shopify-api-private-password";
         var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
        
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const data = JSON.stringify({"redirect":{"path":"http://www.apple.com/forum","target":"http://forums.apple.com"}});
            const options = {
                host: 'store-name.myshopify.com',
                path: '/admin/api/2020-04/redirects.json',
                port: 443,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': auth,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Length': data.length // Added content length
                }
            };
            
            const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
            }
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                } catch(e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });
        // send the request
        // write POST data
        req.write(data)
       req.end();
    });
}
```

I have verified this code and it works fine both on local and in AWS Lambda functions. If you receive 422 now, it means that redirect has already been added.

Besides this consider using the [Shopify API Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) that provides better error handling, rate limiting and other required features. You can also have a look at [Shopify's Official Node library](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api).

Comment: Hi Bilal, you are 100% correct, by adding the write function and data length, the code executed successfully. Will definitely look into the Node Shopify API. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The npm package you linked is **not** the official Node.js library but a third-party one (albeit recognized by Shopify and listed in their dev docs). [This here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-api) is the official one. [GitHub repo here.](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api)